# Setting bootstrap carousel active item selection from the main page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slideshow, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel (slideshow) which is popping up from a page with 12 slides.
On the page I have 12 icons which are referring to the slides on carousel.

How can I click on the main page on item 1 and get item 1 active when popup opens?

here is the main page sample code:

```
          <div id="dialog"> </div>
          [ <a href="#mythDialog" data-toggle="modal">Test Link</a> ] [ <a href="#mythDialog" data-toggle="modal">Test Link 2</a> ] [ <a href="#mythDialog" data-toggle="modal">Test Link 3</a> ]
                    <div id="mythDialog" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

          <h3 id="myModalLabel">Cool work for you</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <!-- Carousel items --->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="active item">
                  <img src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-03.jpg" />
                  <p>1111 Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg" />
                  <p>2222 Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-02.jpg" />
                  <p>3333 Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Carousel nav --> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
       <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

      </div>
      <!-- row -->



                 <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>

                  </div><!-- modal-body -->
                </div> <!-- mythMainDiv -->
```

See it here [Link] (http://jsfiddle.net/barnamah/VCwPE/12/)

Answer (score -1):

if you mean link the image to another page when you click the image i think you can just do:

```
<li><a href="Servers Page.html">
```

Please tell me if this works out